# Change front position for UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I would like to put UIImageView that is shown on button click. That works good if I put it on the last place of Storyboard. The problem occurs when I do programatically some animation, and after that I click button for showing UIImageView and it is not on front position of the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bringSubviewToFront:` method. Something like this:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are adding and removing subviews, it can happen that the order of your views changes.

One solution is to leave the views where they are and only modify the `hidden` property or the `alpha`.

Another solution is to use `insertSubviewAtIndex:` instead of `addSubview:`.

Additionally, you can also use `bringSubviewToFront:` just to make sure.